# Function of two sets intersection

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $U$ be the set of all **nonempty** subsets of $[0,1]$ that are a union of finitely many  closed intervals (where an "interval" that is a single point does not count as an interval). Does there exist a function $f:U\times U\rightarrow U$ such that for any $A,B\in U$:

(a) $f(A,B)\neq [0,1]$.

(b) $f(A,B)\cap A$ and $f(A,B)\cap B$ are of positive length (i.e. Lebesgue measure).

(c)  The length (i.e. Lebesgue measure) of $f(X,B)\cap A$ is maximized at $X=A$, and the length of $f(A,X)\cap B$ is maximized at $X=B$.

Any two of the three conditions can be satisfied:

- $f(A,B)\equiv [0,1]$ satisfy (b) and (c).
- $f(A,B)\equiv Y$ for any fixed $Y\neq [0,1]$ satisfy (a) and (c).
- $f(A,B)$ being any $Y\neq [0,1]$ that intersects both $A$ and $B$ satisfy (a) and (b).

Satisfying all three seems to be impossible though.

Comment: If there is such an $f$, then the image of $f$ is equal to the set $P := \{A | f(A, A) = A\}$, which will be downward closed. I'm currently trying to see if this is necessarily a cover of the interval.

Comment: With respect to (c) condition (b) looks a little bit strange. Can it replaces by (b') $\lambda(f(A,B) \cap A) > 0$  and $\lambda(f(A,B) \cap B) > 0$ if $A,B \not= \emptyset$?

Comment: @DieterKadelka Assuming $\lambda$ refers to the length, then yes

Comment: @pi66: And by length do you mean Lebesgue-measure $\lambda(A)$ or the span $\max A - \min A$ for $A \in U$?

Comment: @DieterKadelka Lebesgue measure

Comment: (b) implies that $f(\emptyset,A)\ne\emptyset$ if $A\ne\emptyset$; (b') does not. Which is it? (Equivalence of the two does not seem obvious.)

Comment: @YaakovBaruch I've edited the problem to deal with empty sets. Hope it's clearer.

Comment: (b) requires that $A \not= \emptyset$ resp. $B \not= \emptyset$, otherwise (b) does not make sense. I think that (b) and (b') are not equivalent, but with (b') it may be easier to show the nonexistence of $f$,

Comment: @DieterKadelka I'd already disallowed empty sets in $U$, so $A$ and $B$ cannot be empty.

Comment: @pi66: I see. Thank you.

Comment: For satisfying two out of three there are nicer examples. $A \cup B$ for all but a). Replace each interval $[m-w,m+w]$ by $[m-w/2,m+w/2]$ and take the union of those satisfies all but c). I suppose $(A \cup B) \cap Y$ does all but b).

Comment: @user44191 how do you show that $f(A, A) \subset A$ for $A$ in the image of $f$?

Comment: @rabota I don't (or at least, don't remember an argument that implies that); I think I should have said $P := \{A|A \subseteq f(A, A) \}$

Comment: @pi66 when you say "maximized at $X=A$", does that mean $A$ is the unique maximizer? (I wouldn't think so, but just wanted to check).

Comment: @mathworker21 No, there can be other maximizers.

Comment: @pi66 You presumably want to change (b) to "positive length" on this problem as well.

Comment: Does $f(A, B) = (A \cup B) - \{.17\}$ work? 

Condition (a) is true since the left hand side doesn't contain $.17$. 

For condition (b), we have $F(A, B) \cap A = A - \{.17\}$ which has positive length since $A$ does.

For condition (c), we note $F(X, B) \cap A \subseteq A-\{.17\} = F(A, B) \cap A$.

Comment: Ah, my suggestion may produce intervals that are not closed. (e.g. if $A = [.17, .18]$, $B = [1/2, 1]$)

Answer (score 0):

Update: this is not quite a complete answer, since (c) might not hold if $A_{\epsilon/2}$ and $B_{\epsilon/2}$ are not disjoint.

My answer to [the variant of this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386375/function-of-two-sets/387124#387124) appears to apply equally to the original here:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. For $X \in U$, let $X_t$ be the "least" subset of $X$ of length $\min(t, \lvert X \rvert)$. In other words, $X_t$ has length $t$ (or is all of $X$) and contains every element of $X$ that is less than the maximum of $X_t$. For example, $([0,1/4] \cup [1/2, 1])_{1/2} = [0, 1/4] \cup [1/2, 3/4]$.

Define $$f(A, B) := A_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}} \cup B_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}.$$

(a): This follows from the definition of the problem, so long as $\epsilon < 1$.

(b): $f(A, B) \cap A \supset A_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$ and therefore has positive length. Similarly for $f(A, B) \cap B$.

(c): The length of $f(X, B) \cap A = (X_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}} \cap A) \cup (B_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}} \cap A)$ is maximized at $X=A$ if $A_{\epsilon/2}$ and $B_{\epsilon/2}$ are disjoint. Similarly for $f(A, X) \cap B$.

A similarly defined $f$ also works if $X_t$ is replaced with another canonically associated subset of $X$ of length $\min(t, \lvert X \rvert)$ (e.g. the "greatest" such subset) or if $\epsilon/2$ is replaced by smaller positive values.