# Image of function contains identity elements

Tags: measure-theory

Let $U$ be the set of all **nonempty** subsets of $[0,1]$ that are a union of finitely many  closed intervals (where an "interval" that is a single point does not count as an interval). Let $f:U\times U\rightarrow U$ be such that for any $A,B\in U$:

(a) $f(A,B)\neq [0,1]$.

(b) $f(A,B)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ and $f(A,B)\cap B\neq\emptyset$.

(c)  The length (i.e. Lebesgue measure) of $f(X,B)\cap A$ is maximized at $X=A$, and the length of $f(A,X)\cap B$ is maximized at $X=B$.

Is it true that the image of $f$ must be equal to the set $\{A\mid f(A,A)=A\}$?

*Note*: The original [unsolved question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312603/function-of-two-sets-intersection) asked whether such $f$ exists. The claim of this question is made in the comments of that question, but the commenter could not recall its proof or whether the proof ever existed.

Comment: (My deleted answer below is foolishly wrong ... should have proofread it before posting.)

Comment: Does condition (c) mean that those are unique maximisers, or could the maxima also be achieved elsewhere?

Comment: @LSpice The maxima could also be achieved elsewhere.